# WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs.Cancel not working on WebBrowser.Navigating?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx), a check box, a button and the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.Navigating += new WebBrowserNavigatingEventHandler(webBrowser1_Navigating);
    }

    void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if(checkBox1.Checked) e.Cancel = true;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=hi&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=9cebbf5a0cce78cd");
    }
}
```

So, after clicking button1 and going to the Google results I check the checkBox1 so that it should cancel. It works for some links, but it doesn't cancel navigation when I click on "Next" or "Previous" or any of the results pages at the bottom. You can test it yourself. Here's the documentation for the [WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.WEBBROWSERNAVIGATINGEVENTARGS);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true). The question is what's wrong with my code and how can I get the WebBrowser to cancel navigation for every link. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the event handler is correctly hooked up that should work (it certainly did for me).

First thing to do is to ensure `webBrowser1_Navigating` is being called -- put a break point on it.

Comment: already checked. It is being called. Are you sure it worked for you? Did you try clicking on the "Next" or "Previous" links on google?

Comment: Well, well.... I just tried it again and it just worked. Weird. I'll keep you posted...

Comment: It is not working within real mobile device (Samsung Galaxy S7 if someone need info with Android 8.0). It just always ignores Cancel being set to true.

Just to reproduce - open a real website, put inside it somewhere (a button for example) with JS code "window.location = 'some other url';" ... What happens is webBrowser1_Navigating is called, inside it goes though e.Cancel = true; but then gets into webBrowser1_Navigated with success state and the webview is navigated to the given URL... so not working at all.

Comment: @VasilPopov `WebBrowser` is a WinForms control (note the date of the question). How are you running such an app on a mobile?